# Maxlength tag not working in jsf

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, maxlength

max length not working for me. please help me.

```
<h:inputTextarea id="commentValue"
maxlength="255"
value="#{commentBean.commentValue}"`enter code here`
onfocus="if (this.value == 'Saisir votre commentaire ici') {this.value = '';}"
                                    onblur="if (jQuery.trim(this.value) == '') {this.value = 'Saisir votre commentaire ici';}"
nkeypress="addCommentOnEnter(event);"
size="100" cols="112" rows="3"> </h:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: 'for me also'? What do you mean?

Comment: wrongly added .. sorry

Comment: also its working for me now. I used jquery because it's in client end.